# comma in site url sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I pass comma(,) in site url it show error while loading.but if I pass %2C(hexa code for comma) then is is passing without error.
Can anyone help me with c# code which auto convert any site url which contain comma to %2C.
Like if there is url : www.google.com/my,name.pdf
then it should pass as www.google.com/my%2C.pdf

do I need to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode
please give me the full c# syntax

Comment: Seems this question is off-topic. Can you further elaborate why this problem relates to SharePoint? As it stand now it seems that this question is asp.net related, and should be asked on stack overflow

Comment: Can you provide me the link where I can post the question.

Comment: You can refer to the main network site: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pepozzo nearly had it!

```
string url = "www.google.com/my" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(",")+"name.pdf";
```

correct method would return:

```
   www.google.com/my%2Cname.pdf
```

pepozzo result would return:

```
   http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2fmy%2Cname.pdf
```

only encode the part you need! otherwise it comes out with garbage like encoding the `/` ;)

or manual

```
string url = "www.google.com/my,name.pdf";
url = url.Replace(",", "%2C");
```

this method is slightly better! it gets the url, then replaces any instance of `,` with `%2C` and it should return the url value of:

```
www.google.com/my%2Cname.pdf
```

same goes with:

```
www.google.com/my,name,is,ali.pdf
```

output would be:

```
www.google.com/my%2Cname%2Cis%2Cali.pdf
```

why is this method better? because you dont need to know the position of `,` witin the string! this allows conversion of any instance of `,` easy and hassle free!

**EDIT**

**HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode Method**

```
Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use UrlEncode.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx

as iv said in my example the same is noted in msdn:

**HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

saying that you can do:

```
string url = "www.google.com/my,name.pdf";
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url).Replace(",", "%2C");
```

Comment: Hi ali! I'm using UrlPathEncode not UrlEncode. It should save the http:// part from encoding. Now checking MSDN I've seen the advice, so it's always suggested to use the UrlEncode.

Comment: just updated the answer. it uses the UrlEncode, UrlPathEncode uses UrlEncode but attaching the replace specific to only encoding , rather than anything else that you wouldnt want! say you might have " or > or <

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string url = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("http://www.google.com/my,.pdf");
```

As suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp#comment438337_575843